# Error when compiling a multicast listener

Tags: c, sockets, multicast

i am trying to compile a multicast listener but gcc finds an error in `struct ip_mreq mreq` declaration.The error is `"storage size of 'mreq' isn't known"` What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (and yes, I was including `<netinet/in.h>`). Adding

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
```

at the top of my .c file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your program includes `<netinet/in.h>`, or wherever it is defined in your system. Also, some systems require that the header files be included in a particular order. So depending on where the error is being reported at, you may need to change the order of your header file inclusions to make sure the dependencies are satisfied.